# SSD intermittent stall (100% busy for 15 seconds)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, freeze

Disk access on my new computer (Windows 10) often freezes for ~15 seconds. It might happen more often when concatenating files on disk (but that's just my feeling, I don't really have any data to back that up). The mouse pointer is still working normally during the freeze, and applications only using RAM functions normally.

The error has been there since I've built the computer (a week back).

I expect this problem to be tricky, and not really hoping for a solution, but if you could point me in the right direction of what to try I'd be very thankful!

### Hardware

- Disk: Kingston SA400S37480G (480GB SSD)
- Motherboard: MSI Z370-A (Intel Z370 chipset, DDR4-4133+, SATAIII)
- CPU: Intel Core i5-8600K
- RAM: 2x8GB HyperX Predator DDR4-2400MHz

### Symptoms

Please excuse the Swedish screenshots.

No single process is using disk (thus it's a stall):

[image]

However, no actual disk access is happening during the stall:

[image]

In perfmon we can see that the disk queue builds up during a stall:

[image]

### What I've tried

- Installed newest vendor-specific drivers.
- Flashed newest BIOS and SSD firmwares.
- Stopped and disabled a bunch of services such as Windows Search, BITS, DiagTrack, Superfetch and so forth.
- Removed some scheduled tasks such as WinInet, WinInetServer, etc.
- Replaced the SATA cable.
- Changed the SATA port on the motherboard.
- Ran MemTest86 V7.5 (4 passes took 3 hours, no errors detected).
- Ran smartmontools disk long test ("Completed without error"). The freeze occurred several times during the test.
- Ran failsafe mode. The freeze occurred several times during failsafe mode.

I've also tried a bunch of settings in the registry, such as:

[image]

(Which can be found online as a potential fix for these kinds of errors when iaStoreAC.sys is used.)

## Summary

This happens when I listen to music, watch Youtube, game, code, do nothing. Since the problem seems invariant with regards to software, drivers and settings, I'm more inclined to think it's hardware-related. I guess 1 bit error per 10<sup>8</sup>, either on the bus or SATA, could result in something like this? What do I try next?

Comment: To confirm when you specify that you have installed the vendor specific drivers that you have installed both "Intel Management Engine Driver" and "Intel Chipset Driver" ? - I ask this as I have seen similar behaviour when these have been missed.

Comment: @CraftyB: yes, both are installed.

Comment: Have you checked the drives SMART status?  How full is the drive?

Comment: @Keltari: SMART status ok; I've tried SMART both on and off. Half full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problems were caused by a faulty SSD. When I replaced it with an equally big one (but from another manufacturer), everything became smooth as silk.

**Edit by other:** We are experiencing same issue on same SSD model, solved updating SSD firmware to release SBFKB1C3 by KingSton SSD Manager v 1.1.1.8.

Comment: I am having the exact same model+size as OP, and am experiencing stalls (much longer than 15s) and generally PATHETIC I/O perf for an SSD. I am running firmware SBFK71E0 and Kingston SSD Manager 1.1.1.8 says that "No Firmware Update Available". I might have to take this one back to the store.

Comment: @joonas.fi yep, looks like that model has problems. Let me know if replacing the HD solved your problem.

Comment: yeah, it was definitely a faulty one. I even changed SATA data- and power cables - issue persisted. I even cloned the SSD to another SSD, ran it for two weeks and it didn't stall once (previously I had many stalls each day). So problem was not my SATA port or my computer. Funny thing is, the SSD drive I cloned the faulty drive to was the exact same Kingston model (I had bought another one off of a sale later without realizing that it's he same model). So not all of them are faulty. I returned the faulty one to the store.